# Changing variables inside a list in python (backtracking)

Tags: python, backtracking

I'm trying to solve a sudoku puzzle using python for that I'm using a 3D list, 2 dimensions for the sudoku board and a 3rd dimension to store the changes on the board and to be able to backtrack whenever a given cell cant be filled. I've written some code but I've reached a problem that I cant figure out, whenever the program assigns a number to a cell in the 3D list, it also changes the number in other cells. My code is as follows:

```
import math


def square_id(grid, ni, nj):
    if ni >= 9:
        return ("the matrix doesn't have the right size or component doesn't exist")
    elif nj >= 9:
        return ("the matrix doesn't have the right size or component doesn't exist")
    elif ni < 3:
        if nj < 3:
            return 1
        elif nj < 6:
            return 2
        elif nj < 9:
            return 3
    elif ni < 6:
        if nj < 3:
            return 4
        elif nj < 6:
            return 5
        elif nj < 9:
            return 6
    elif ni < 9:
        if nj < 3:
            return 7
        elif nj < 6:
            return 8
        elif nj < 9:
            return 9


def sudo_rules(grid, ni, nj):
    if grid[ni][nj] == 0:
        return False
    for i in range(0, 9):
        if grid[i][nj] == grid[ni][nj] and i != ni:
            return False
    for j in range(0, 9):
        if grid[ni][j] == grid[ni][nj] and j != nj:
            return False
    for i in range(0, 3):
        for j in range(0, 3):
            k = square_id(grid, ni, nj)
            l = int(math.ceil(k / 3)) - 1
            c = k % 3 - 1
            if c == -1:
                c = 2
            if grid[3 * l + i][3 * c + j] == grid[ni][nj] and 3 * c + j != nj and 3 * l + i != ni:
                return False


grid0 = [[0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0],
        [0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0],
        [5, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 4, 0, 6],
        [0, 5, 0, 2, 0, 0, 7, 0, 1],
        [9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8],
        [0, 7, 0, 1, 0, 0, 6, 0, 5]]

grid= []
pos = []
for i in range(0, 30):
    grid.append([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
    pos.append([1, 0, 0])

grid[0]=grid0

k = 0
i = 0
j = 0
n = 1

while i < 9:
    if j == 9:
        j = 0
    while j < 9:
        if sudo_rules(grid[k], i, j) == False:
            while n < 11:
                if n == 10:
                    break
                print(k, i, j)
                print("grid[0]:", grid[0])
                grid[k][i][j] = n
                print("grid[0]:", grid[0])
                print("grid[1]:", grid[1])
                if sudo_rules(grid[k], i, j) != False:
                    pos[k] = [n, i, j]
                    n = 1
                    grid[k + 1] = grid[k]
                    k = k + 1
                    break
                n = n + 1
                if k==1:
                    exit()
        if n == 10:
            break
        j = j + 1
    i = i + 1
    if n == 10:
        print(grid[0])
        k = k - 1
        n = pos[k][0] + 1
        i = pos[k][1]
        j = pos[k][2]

for i in range(0, 9):
    for j in range(0, 9):
        if sudo_rules(grid[k], i, j) == False:
            print("Wrong")
            break
```

My problem is in this line:

```
                print(k, i, j)
                print("grid[0]:", grid[0])
                grid[k][i][j] = n
                print("grid[0]:", grid[0])
                print("grid[1]:", grid[1])
```

I dont understand why changing grid[1][0][1] also changes grid[0][0][1]. Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: draw it out and label it

Comment: you are most likely just duplicating a list, not its values, so if you change the list, it's duplicate also gets changed

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
grid[k + 1] = grid[k]
```

It looks like you expect it to create a copy of your grid, but instead it just assigns the same grid asssigned to `grid[k]` to `grid[k + 1]` as well.

If you need a copy of some object, you can use `copy()` or `deepcopy()`, depending on the data structure.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this statement:

```
grid[k + 1] = grid[k]
```

That does not make a copy of the grid.  That merely stores another reference to the SAME grid.  Changing through either element changes the one grid.  Note that `grid[k+1] = grid[k][:]` is not enough; that creates a new row list, but the rows in that list will still contain references to the old rows.  You would have to use `deepcopy`.

However, it would be more efficient just to stack up the moves you made at each step.  That makes it easy to backtrack, and you can recreate the grid after backtracking easily by scanning through the set of moves.

Another however, solving Sudoku by brute force is not really "solving" them at all.  I believe you will have to make 9!x9! attempts, which is about 131 billion.

Comment: Just a note: backtracking is not the same as brute forcing a problem. Brute force only takes the basic constraints into account and tries all possible solutions until it finds a valid one, backtracking walks a tree of solutions and as soon as it finds a branch can no long be valid, it effectively prunes the entire branch of solutions.

Comment: You're quibbling over semantics here.  There are very good algorithms for solving Sudokus analytically.  This code uses none of them.  It just blindly tries solutions until one cell fails.  That's brute force.